# Sphinx "Examples" or "References" heading

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, heading

I am writing Sphinx documentation for a Python project and I would like to have a section called "Examples" but it does not get properly formatted.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
r"""
.. My Python Module

This is my Python module.

.. contents:: Table of Contents
  :local:

Description
***********

This is the module description

Examples
********

This are the module examples
"""
# My module code
```

When I build the documentation, I get the desired header for the first case ("Description") but the "Examples" heading is neither included in the table of contents nor formatted properly as heading (only bold).

The same happens with "References" and other keywords used by `automodapi`.

Comment: I think you need a primary heading at the start of the docstring. Perhaps use `=` as the underline for "My Python Module" instead of using an reST comment of `..`?

Comment: With "vanilla" Sphinx (without the automodapi extension), it works fine for me.